# HTML5 video captions are not displayed on IE11 (Nginx server)

Tags: html5-video, internet-explorer-11

Is someone who stumbled upon and has a solution for this issue where HTML5 videos are not showing closed captions on IE11 browser only +OS Win8, Win10 (not reproducible on MS Edge 40, Chrome 66 or Firefox 60.0.1 browser)?

Later edit: Setup = Nginx server + IE11

Here is a demo link where you can find a HTML5 video with CC:
https://testdrive-archive.azurewebsites.net/Graphics/VideoCaptions/Default.html

Open this with IE 11 and turn on CC.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my specific problem - this is a IE11 issue: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8832169/